# How to upload photo to my hosting server folder directory

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload, image-uploading

Hello I was trying to upload a photo from a website I made, to the website's hosting server's folder directory (/public_html/upload/) using php. but the folder always shows up empty. I dont know what am I doing wrong. can anyone help?

this is the html file:

```
 <div id = "forms">
  <form action="add_data.php" method="post" form enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <div id = "info1">
   <p> <h2> Accident Report Form </h2> </p>
   </div>
    <div id = "info2"><p> Please fill in the form below to report an accident </p></div>

      <ol>

       <li> <label for = "name" >  Name: </label> 

          <input "type = "text" name = "name" id = "name"/> </li>

         <li> <label for = "location" > Location of the accident: </label>

          <input "type = "text" name = "location" id = "location" /> </li>

         <li> <label for = "road" > Road Name: </label>

          <input "type = "text" name = "road" id = "road"/> </li>


                 <li> <label for = "image" > Image: </label>

          <input type="file" name="photo"><br> </li>


      </ol>
     <div id = "submit"><button type="submit" >Submit</button> </div><br>    


  </form>


 </div>
```

And, this is the **add_data.php** file:

```
 <?php
$target = "/public_html/upload"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
   ?>
```

Comment: maybe you can read php file upload docs http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php ...

Answer (score 1):

**Imporved working Code:**

```
<?php
   $target = "/public_html/upload/"; 
   $target = $target .$_FILES['photo']['name'];
   $pic=($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
   move_uploaded_file($pic, $target);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code to work.

HTML - is ok but could be formatted better, try a online formatter tool
http://jsbeautifier.org/.
Also, form opening tag should look like this

```
<form action="add_data.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

PHP - Explanation provided in the comments

```php
<?php

// Uploaded file will be stored in a temporary location and needs to
// be moved to a destination directory and given the original filename
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

//  prepare target pathname
//
$target = "/public_html/upload";
$targetName = $_FILES['photo']['name'];

// get temp file name
//
$tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];

// use php's move_uploaded_file() function
// to copy temp file to final destination
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $targetDir . $targetName);
```