# How to Upload images into folder directory on the server using php

Tags: php

I am trying to upload images onto server.

On the Server the folder name:{photo}

I check the permissions on the folder and it currently on 0755.

When I run my php code, I get this error code:

"Error uploading file - check destination is writeable."

The post that was similar to my issues is this: [How to upload photo to my hosting server folder directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520260/how-to-upload-photo-to-my-hosting-server-folder-directory)

but I already have these functions in my code:

Here my php code:

```
<?php

$filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
$filesize = $_FILES["file_img"]["size"];
$fileinfo = getimagesize($_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"]);
$filewidth = $fileinfo[0];
$fileheight = $fileinfo[1];
$filepath = "../photo/".$filename;
$filepath_thumb = "../photo/thumb/".$filename;




if($_POST['btn_upload'])
{
    $sPhotoFileName = $filename;
    $nPhotoSize = $filesize;
    $sTempFileName = $filetmp;
    chmod($filepath_thumb,0755);
    chmod($filepath,0755);

if(file_exists('photo/' . $_FILES['file_img']['name'])){
    die('File with that name already exists.');
}else{

if ($sPhotoFileName) // file uploaded
{   $aFileNameParts = explode(".", $sPhotoFileName);
    $sFileExtension = end($aFileNameParts); // part behind last dot
    if ($sFileExtension != "jpg"
        && $sFileExtension != "png"
        && $sFileExtension != "gif")
    {   die ("Choose a JPG for the photo");
    }
}

if($_FILES['file_img']['error'] > 0){
    die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}

    if ($nPhotoSize == 0)
    {   die ("Sorry. The upload of $sPhotoFileName has failed.
Search a photo smaller than 300K, using the button.");
    }
    if ($nPhotoSize > 30240000000)
    {   die ("Sorry.
The file $sPhotoFileName is larger than 300K.
Advice: reduce the photo using a drawing tool.");
    }
    // read photo

    $oTempFile = fopen($sTempFileName, "r");
    $sBinaryPhoto = fread($oTempFile, fileSize($sTempFileName));
    // Try to read image
    $nOldErrorReporting = error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_WARNING)); // ingore warnings
    $oSourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($sBinaryPhoto); // try to create image
    error_reporting($nOldErrorReporting);
    if (!$oSourceImage) // error, image is not a valid jpg
    { die ("Sorry.
It was not possible to read photo $sPhotoFileName.
Choose another photo in JPG format.");
    }
}
 $nWidth = imagesx($oSourceImage); // get original source image width
        $nHeight = imagesy($oSourceImage); // and height
        // create small thumbnail
        $nDestinationWidth = 80;
        $nDestinationHeight = 60;
    //$oDestinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
        $oDestinationImage = imagecreate($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
    /*$oResult = imagecopyresampled(
        $oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,
        $nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
    */
        imagecopyresized($oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage,0, 0, 0, 0,$nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight,$nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image
        ob_start(); // Start capturing stdout.
        imageJPEG($oDestinationImage); // As though output to browser.
        $sBinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents(); // the raw jpeg image data.
        ob_end_clean(); // Dump the stdout so it does not screw other output.

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO UploadImg (img_name, img_path, img_type) VALUES ('$sPhotoFileName', '$filepath', '$filetype')";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                    echo "Records added successfully.";
                } else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                }


    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"],"../photo/".$_FILES["file_img"]["name"])){
           die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
       echo "Error Code: " .$_FILES["file_img"]["name"] . "<br>";
    }else{



    $sBinaryThumbnail = addslashes($sBinaryThumbnail);
    $oDatabase = $link;
    mysqli_select_db("upload", $oDatabase);
    $sQuery = "insert into Uploadimg (thumbnail) VALUES ('$sBinaryThumbnail')";
    echo $sQuery;
    mysqli_query($sQuery, $oDatabase);
    die('File uploaded successfully.');
    mysqli_close($link);

    }
}
    ?>
```

Now I read an article say that even if your folder permission setup up to do all three read, write, and executed on all three level. the code still will not be able to read it depending on the settings on the server.

So I am confused and looking for clarification. Please assist me?

Comment: I am guessing but try `$filepath = "photo/".$filename;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried that too. IT did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the image by binary data encoded and save the file with the image format on the server.

Answer (score 0):

755 means it is not world writable. You can set it writable and executable with 777.

This is still vulnerable as anyone with access to your server os can write to the folder, so you should probably just make the web server user the owner of the folder and keep the permissions as they are now. If you're running apache, the user is usually www-data or apache.

Comment: it a server at my university, im using FTP application WinScp to login into the server to host my webpages

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out you gotta set the GID and UID permissions[filepermission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np5cL.jpg)

The set group identification GID allows the owner to execute all applications to read, write and pull to the folder.

Same thing with the User identification UID. the problem is the your folder will be wide open for strangers to manipulate it but it works.

My images are uploading into the folder. Tell me what yall think?

Answer (score 0):

First in your php.ini put

```
file_uploads = On
```

Next, create an HTML form that allow users to choose the image file they want to upload:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

Make sure that the form uses method="post"
Then use the php code below to upload image

```js
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```